# Getting error: cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a requirement to pass `List<Map<String, String>>` as a parameter for REST GET API. I need to know how this can be passed from Postman or similar tool.

I tried to set it as a BODY for a GET API, it is giving me errors.

```js
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
      var newpath = 'D:/nodejs/images/' + files.filetoupload.name;
      fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
        res.end();
      });
    });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, [search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=formidable.IncomingForm+path+site:stackoverflow.com); if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.
I suugest to use the POST method instead of a GET